# how to check error in json means 500 error in asp.net mvc

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

when i send json. it may be have something wrong. server does not accept request and give error 500 even i seding a json he return a error page in json. how i can check that i have 500 error in json when as result after my json is gone to server.

how i can check that server return 500 error i am talking about .NET

Answer (score 0, accepted):

according to the docu

```
error(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown)
```

[docu](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

and you need the enum-members of `textStatus`, which can be found [here](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/jquery-ajax-textstatus-documented)